# Can't post WordPress links to my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, links, wordpress

I can't post links to my WordPress site on my Facebook business page. The URL does not contain any unusual or sensitive worlds (www.genesiskravmaga.com). When I try to post the link, there is no option for adding a thumbnail image and when submitted I get the "oops, something went wrong" message. I've seen this error reported elsewhere but have never seen a solution. Is it a Facebook problem or do I need to add some code to my site to allow Facebook to post the link?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be related to the [Flexo Facebook Manager](http://www.flexostudio.com/flexo-facebook-manager.html) Wordpress plugin you have installed: both the `og:image` and `og:description` meta properties in the Wordpress-generated HTML on your website are blank.

What happens when you disable said plugin?

Comment: Sorry - just saw your answer, thanks for the reply. I disabled Flexo Facebook Manager but am still getting the same problem. Is there any code I could manually enter into the WP templates for facebook to read?